# Concat function returns 1 on MySQL query on Flask

Tags: mysql, flask, mysql-python

I run `MySql` query in flask with `concat` function and it always returns 1.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs( job_id, job_name, company, who_created) 
VALUES(%s,%s, %s,%s)",(job_id,job_name, company,
[cur.execute("select concat(first_name , ' ' , last_name)
from employees where username = %s", [username] ) ] ) )
```

`who_created` always returns `1`.

When I run query on MySQLWorkbench, it works fine and returns `first name + last name`.

Problem is not with concat function, because even if I run it without concat, I get the "str object is not callable" error

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`cur.execute` will return the number of rows found. To get the returned data, you need to use another call after the execute:

```
cur.execute("select concat(first_name , ' ' , last_name) from employees where username = %s", [username] )
name_rs = cur.fetchall()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs( job_id, job_name, company, who_created) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)",(job_id, job_name, company, name_rs[0][0] ) )
```

Comment: when I run your code I get the 
builtins.KeyError
KeyError: 0